# why do they use (+) in where clause for checking not null in a column eg emp_name(+) IS NOT NULL

Tags: oracle

Why do we use a (+) operator in the where clause for instance emp_name(+) IS NOT NULL, emp_name IS NOT NULL AND emp_name(+) IS NOT NULL is the same

Answer (score 1):

Because removing the (+) from the column you're checking is not null turns the join from an outer join into what is effectively an inner join. Leaving the (+) in tells oracle to get all rows from the "main" table, and then match any rows from the outer joined table where that column is not null.

See the below for an example of why the "extra" (+) is needed:

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1,
       t2
where  t1.id = t2.id (+)
and    t2.val (+) is not null
order by t1.id;

        ID VAL       ID_1 VAL_1
---------- --- ---------- -----
         1 a                   
         2 b                   
         3 c            3 d

with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1,
       t2
where  t1.id = t2.id (+)
and    t2.val is not null
order by t1.id;

        ID VAL       ID_1 VAL_1
---------- --- ---------- -----
         3 c            3 d
```

You can see the difference easier if you convert the query to the ANSI join syntax:

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1
       left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id and t2.val is not null)
order by t1.id;

        ID VAL       ID_1 VAL_1
---------- --- ---------- -----
         1 a                   
         2 b                   
         3 c            3 d  

with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1
       left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
where  t2.val is not null
order by t1.id;

        ID VAL       ID_1 VAL_1
---------- --- ---------- -----
         3 c            3 d
```

In other words, it's the difference between the "col is not null" predicate being a part of the outer join condition, or a filter in the where clause.

You'll note as well that having the "t2.val is not null" in the where clause has the effect of turning the outer join into an inner join, despite the fact that you've requested an outer join:

```
with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1
       left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
--where  t2.val is not null
order by t1.id;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |        |       |    12 (100)|          |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY   |      |      3 |    33 |    12  (17)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |     1/0/0|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER|      |      3 |    33 |    11  (10)| 00:00:01 |  1156K|  1156K|     1/0/0|
|   3 |    VIEW          |      |      3 |    18 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL    |      |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|   5 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   6 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   7 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   8 |    VIEW          |      |      2 |    10 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   9 |     UNION-ALL    |      |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|  10 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|  11 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

with t1 as (select 1 id, 'a' val from dual union all
            select 2 id, 'b' val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'c' val from dual),
     t2 as (select 1 id, null val from dual union all
            select 3 id, 'd' val from dual)
select *
from   t1
       left outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
where  t2.val is not null
order by t1.id;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |        |       |    10 (100)|          |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY   |      |      1 |    11 |    10  (20)| 00:00:01 |  2048 |  2048 |     3/0/0|
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN      |      |      1 |    11 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |  1156K|  1156K|     3/0/0|
|   3 |    VIEW          |      |      2 |    10 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL    |      |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|*  5 |      FILTER      |      |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|   6 |       FAST DUAL  |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   7 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   8 |    VIEW          |      |      3 |    18 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|   9 |     UNION-ALL    |      |        |       |            |          |       |       |          |
|  10 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|  11 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
|  12 |      FAST DUAL   |      |      1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the change from HASH JOIN OUTER to HASH JOIN in the row with id = 2 in the 2nd explain plan.